# The model item passed into the dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

[1] i have this Error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List but this dictionary 
    requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[OpenOrderFrame

```
i have my controller as this : 

public class ItemsController : Controller
        {
            private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();    
        // GET: Items
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {                      
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "Name";
            ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Name" ? "Loc_desc" : "Location";
            IEnumerable<Item> items = db.Items;
            var jo = (from a in items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Catagorie, x.ItemName })
                                     .Select(g => new
                                     {
                                         Category = g.Key.Catagorie,
                                         ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                                         Quantity = g.Sum(s => s.ItemQty),
                                         Location = g.First().Location
                                     })
                                    select a);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
            {
                items = items.Where(s => s.ItemName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                           || s.Catagorie.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())||
                                           s.Location.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).ToList().ToPagedList(page ??1,  20);
                //}

            }
            else
            {
                items = items.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
            }
            return View(jo);
```

and in my View i have the code as this:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Food";
}
```

[2] please help me with the code , I'm so fed up 
i want to pass the list of items in jo to view page.. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You are returning to View  `jo` (`View(jo)` here:

```
return View(jo);
```

which is not of type `IPagedList<OpenOrderFramework.Models.Item>`.

It looks like you have mistakenly passed `jo` variable instead of `items` back to View method. Changing it to passed `items` should fix it.

**Side Note:** I am not sure what you are doing as your creating `jo` by doing some linq on `items` but then later down you are again doing some operations on `items` and returning instead `jo`  back. So you need to remove the code which is extra there.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `jo` but don't you want to return `items`?

```
 return View(items);
```

Or make `jo` a PagedList...

Comment: i want to return the list of items in var(jo)

Comment: Then you have to make `jo`  a `PagedList`

Comment: can you help me with that please

Comment: `return View(jo.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));`

Comment: it complained of this : Additional information: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.